# jquery multiplication - behind the scene calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this calculator:

[image: calc]

This is my html :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="twenty columns">
        <h2 class="secondary-title text-red2">Mortgage Utilisation Calculator</h2>
        <form>
            <div class="row forminput">
                <div class="ten columns">
                    <p class="slider-label">Daily Flexi Account Balance (RM)</p>
                    <input type="text" class="daily-flexi-accbalance strictly-numbers" value="200000" />
                </div>
                <div class="ten columns">
                    <p class="slider-label">Number of Days in Month</p>
                    <div class="field type-dropdown">
                        <div class="picker picker-dd2">
                            <select class="dropdown2 numdays-month">
                                <option value="0">Please select</option>
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                <option value="6">6</option>
                                <option value="7">7</option>
                                <option value="8">8</option>
                                <option value="9">9</option>
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                <option value="11">11</option>
                                <option value="12">12</option>
                                <option value="13">13</option>
                                <option value="14">14</option>
                                <option value="15">15</option>
                                <option value="16">16</option>
                                <option value="17">17</option>
                                <option value="18">18</option>
                                <option value="19">19</option>
                                <option value="20">20</option>
                                <option value="21">21</option>
                                <option value="22">22</option>
                                <option value="23">23</option>
                                <option value="24">24</option>
                                <option value="25">25</option>
                                <option value="26">26</option>
                                <option value="27">27</option>
                                <option value="28">28</option>
                                <option value="29">29</option>
                                <option value="30">30</option>
                                <option value="31">31</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ten columns">
                    <p class="slider-label">Current Facility Limit (RM)</p>
                    <input type="text" class="curr-facilitylimit numeric-only" value="500000" />
                </div>
                <div class="ten columns">
                    <p class="slider-label">Excess Payment (RM)</p>
                    <input type="text" class="curr-facilitylimit numeric-only" value="" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

        <div class="row bg-gray12">
            <div class="ten columns bg-gray12 data-box2">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="twelve columns">Sum of Daily Flexi Account Balance</div>
                    <div class="eight columns text-right calc-result-sumflexiacc " data-prefix="RM " data-suffix="">RM 0</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ten columns bg-gray11 data-box2">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="twelve columns">Monthly Utilisation Rate</div>
                    <div class="eight columns text-right calc-result-mthly-utilisationrate text-right" data-prefix="RM " data-suffix="">0 %</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- <div class="row bg-gray9 data-box2 font-brighter">
            <div class="fifteen columns ">Total Amount Payable</div>
            <div class="five columns text-right calc-result-totalpayable" data-prefix="RM " data-suffix="">RM 0</div>

        </div> -->

    </div>
</div>
```

I have this function to calculate the sum of daily flexi acc

```
function calcSumDailyFlexiAccBalance() {
    var numDaysMonth;

    $(".numdays-month").on('change', function() {
       numDaysMonth =   parseInt($(".numdays-month").val(), 10);
    });

    var dailyFlexi = parseInt($(".daily-flexi-accbalance").val(), 10);
    var resultDaysFlexi = numDaysMonth * dailyFlexi;
    var roundResult = Math.round(resultDaysFlexi/100)*100
}
```

In order to get the value for field: sum of daily flexi account balance - the calculation will be daily flexi account balance * num of days - the result is rounded up to the nearest hundredth.

**FOR EXAMPLE**
daily flexi account balance is : 265806,
num of day : 31,
the sum of daily flexi acc balance will be : 8,239,986 and the correct output will be 8,240,000

for some reason I don't think my calculation is outputting the correct amount because I'm getting NaN

Comment: When do you call `calcSumDailyFlexiAccBalance` ?

Comment: just right after the function there's $(document).ready(function(e) {
    calcSumDailyFlexiAccBalance();
});

Comment: You code will not update when any value of input will change...

Comment: The output is `8,240,000` because `8,239,986/100` is `82,399`, which when rounded is `82,400`.  `82,400 * 100` is `8,240,000`.  Try doing `Math.round(resultDaysFlexi/100.0)*100.0`

Comment: @Tibrogargan yes I know, that's the correct output. I'm just asking the process of getting that output

Comment: BTW, your question is kind of unclear.  You could explain what you think the correct amount is

Comment: @Tibrogargan I did

Comment: No, you didn't.  You said what the balance is and what the output is.  I'm assuming that the balance is the correct amount but maybe it's not.  What exactly is wrong with the output?

Comment: @rory-h "the correct output will be 8,240,000 **for some reason** I don't think my calculation is outputting the correct amount." What is the reason?? What do you expect it to be?

Comment: @Slayther I'm getting NaN

Comment: @Tibrogargan I'm getting NaN

Comment: The problem is not in the code you have shown.  I'll post an answer just so you can see your code (slightly modified) is working correctly.

Comment: The problem is, you are only calling your function when the document loads. The month `select` is not set at start. Even though you change the month selection, you aren't calling your function again.

Comment: My assumption is you intend to call `calcSumDailyFlexiAccBalance` whenever any of the fields on the form are changed, but I also think you have not posted all your code - so it's hard to tell what's going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the number of days dropdown, it will log the output of your calculation, which looks correct (i.e.  No `NaN`)

```js
function init() {
 $(".numdays-month").on('change',
  function() {
   var numDaysMonth;
   numDaysMonth = parseInt($(".numdays-month").val(), 10);
   var dailyFlexi = parseInt($(".daily-flexi-accbalance").val(), 10);
   var resultDaysFlexi = numDaysMonth * dailyFlexi;
   var roundResult = Math.round(resultDaysFlexi/100)*100
   console.log(roundResult);
  }
 );
}

$(document).ready(init);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
     <div class="row">

            <div class="twenty columns">
                <h2 class="secondary-title text-red2">Mortgage Utilisation Calculator</h2>
                <form>
                    <div class="row forminput">

                        <div class="ten columns">
                            <p class="slider-label">Daily Flexi Account Balance (RM)</p>
                            <input type="text" class="daily-flexi-accbalance strictly-numbers" value="200000" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="ten columns">
                                <p class="slider-label">Number of Days in Month</p>
                                <div class="field type-dropdown">
                                    <div class="picker picker-dd2">
                                        <select class="dropdown2 numdays-month">
                                            <option value="0">Please select</option>
                                            <option value="1">1</option>
                                            <option value="2">2</option>
                                            <option value="3">3</option>
                                            <option value="4">4</option>
                                            <option value="5">5</option>
                                            <option value="6">6</option>
                                            <option value="7">7</option>
                                            <option value="8">8</option>
                                            <option value="9">9</option>
                                            <option value="10">10</option>
                                            <option value="11">11</option>
                                            <option value="12">12</option>
                                            <option value="13">13</option>
                                            <option value="14">14</option>
                                            <option value="15">15</option>
                                            <option value="16">16</option>
                                            <option value="17">17</option>
                                            <option value="18">18</option>
                                            <option value="19">19</option>
                                            <option value="20">20</option>
                                            <option value="21">21</option>
                                            <option value="22">22</option>
                                            <option value="23">23</option>
                                            <option value="24">24</option>
                                            <option value="25">25</option>
                                            <option value="26">26</option>
                                            <option value="27">27</option>
                                            <option value="28">28</option>
                                            <option value="29">29</option>
                                            <option value="30">30</option>
                                            <option value="31">31</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="ten columns">
                            <p class="slider-label">Current Facility Limit (RM)</p>
                            <input type="text" class="curr-facilitylimit numeric-only" value="500000" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="ten columns">
                            <p class="slider-label">Excess Payment (RM)</p>
                            <input type="text" class="curr-facilitylimit numeric-only" value="" />
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </form>

                <div class="row bg-gray12">
                    <div class="ten columns bg-gray12 data-box2">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="twelve columns">Sum of Daily Flexi Account Balance</div>
                            <div class="eight columns text-right calc-result-sumflexiacc " data-prefix="RM " data-suffix="">RM 0</div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="ten columns bg-gray11 data-box2">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="twelve columns">Monthly Utilisation Rate</div>
                            <div class="eight columns text-right calc-result-mthly-utilisationrate text-right" data-prefix="RM " data-suffix="">0 %</div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- <div class="row bg-gray9 data-box2 font-brighter">
                    <div class="fifteen columns ">Total Amount Payable</div>
                    <div class="five columns text-right calc-result-totalpayable" data-prefix="RM " data-suffix="">RM 0</div>

                </div> -->

            </div>
        </div></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `Math.round`.

You're using `Math.round(resultDaysFlexi/100)*100` - so you're rounding it before final multiplication by 100.

Try to remove rounding or apply it only to final result.

Another useful tip is to add `console.log` after every step of calculation and check what is current value of your calculation, so you can see when is it starting to go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your logic in jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hr869sx4/2/) after modifying event bindings. And it is working same as your example. Then what is the problem.

Here is my JS changes:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) { 
  $(".numdays-month").on('change', function() {
    calcSumDailyFlexiAccBalance();
  });

  function calcSumDailyFlexiAccBalance(){
    var numDaysMonth;

    numDaysMonth = parseInt($(".numdays-month").val(), 10);

    var dailyFlexi = parseInt($(".daily-flexi-accbalance").val(), 10);
    var resultDaysFlexi = numDaysMonth * dailyFlexi;
    var roundResult = Math.round(resultDaysFlexi/100)*100;
    $('.calc-result-sumflexiacc').html(roundResult);
  }
});
```